# Solving an equation in an array with loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

An array of 'N' integers, it is necessary to calculate the next equation:

```
у = х1 * (х1 + х2) * (х1 + х2 + х3) * ... * (x1 + ... + xN)
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to find the solution `y`?
2. How to generate random number except of 0?

Code:

```
srand(time(NULL));
const int size = 10;
int arr[size];
int pro=1;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    arr[i] = rand() % 10;
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cout << arr[i] << ' ';
}

cout << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        sum = arr[j];
    }
    pro *= sum;
}
cout << pro << endl;
```

Comment: `sum = arr[j];` should probably be `sum += arr[j];`

Comment: What do you understand by `How to generate random number except 0?` Is this an answer: `arr[i] = 1 + (rand() % 9);` ?

Comment: i meant how to fill array with random numbers except 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to generate random number except 0?

```
arr[i] = rand() % 9 + 1; // rando number in range 1 .. 9
```

> Is there a better way to find the solution y?

```
long  pro = 1;
long  sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sum += arr[i]; // i==0: x1, i==1: x1+x2, i==3: x1+x2+x3, ....
    pro *= sum;
}
```

This should be your code:

```
srand(time(NULL));
const int size = 10;
int arr[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    arr[i] = rand() % 9 + 1;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << ' ';

cout << endl;

long  pro = 1;
long  sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sum += arr[i];
    pro *= sum;
}
cout << pro << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you .. this is what i mean